# GlassFish Jersey transient field?

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, glassfish

I have a small project at my university. I would like to use a REST webserver (on GlassFish) with Jersey.
I tried replace the MOXy to Jackson but I could not do that.

I have a modell class and it is contains few variable. The output is correct JSON or XML. But I want to put Transient annotation to some variable.

The javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransien annotation is not working. I see the variable in the output response.

Here is my modell class:

```
public class Xyz {
    private String a = "value";
    private int b = 3;

    @XmlTransient
    private List<int> list = new LinkedList<>();

    // get, set ..
}
```

And my service class is:

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/json")
    public Response getJSON() {
        return Response.ok(new Xyz()).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    @Path("/xml")
    public Response getXML() {
        return Response.ok(new Xyz()).build();
    }
}
```

The web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.example</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
                <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyFeature</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Where is the problem? Or how to replace with Jackson? I want to use GlassFish.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I use ` @JsonIgnore
` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` but this will only work if you are using jackson for generating the json